# Cancelling input command upon user's request

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am a beginner. I am creating a very basic calculator.

I want to break the program when the user gives the command as "STOP". Here's my code:

```
while d=="yes" or d=="YES" or d=="Yes":
    a=input("Enter: A for additon, B for Subtraction, C for Multiplication, D for Division: ")
    b=int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    c=int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    if a=="A":
        print(b+c)
    elif a=="B":
        print(b-c)
    elif a=="C":
        print(b*c)
    elif a=="D":
        print(b/c)
    elif a=="STOP":
        break
```

I tried typing "STOP" but the output comes like this:

```
Do you want to calculate more? YES
Enter: A for additon, B for Subtraction, C for Multiplication, D for Division: B
Enter the first number: 46
Enter the second number: 23
23
Enter: A for additon, B for Subtraction, C for Multiplication, D for Division: STOP
Enter the first number: 1
Enter the second number: 23
```

After it receives the input "STOP", it asks for the first and the second number again which are the b and c variables. Either it should ask again to calculate more, or it should terminate upon the user's request. How can I make the changes??

Comment: You unconditionally ask for input of the *a* and *b* values **before** testing *a* for 'STOP'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange. You are so very close with your code. You need to test for the "STOP" command before you call `input()` for the two numbers. If you rearrange your code like this

```
while d=="yes" or d=="YES" or d=="Yes":
    a=input("Enter: A for additon, B for Subtraction, C for Multiplication, D for Division: ")
    if a=="STOP":
        break
    b=int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    c=int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    if a=="A":
        print(b+c)
    elif a=="B":
        print(b-c)
    elif a=="C":
        print(b*c)
    elif a=="D":
        print(b/c)
```

You should get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! It worked out well!!!